# Create a loop to insert dates for a date range

Tags: postgresql

**Background**:
Holiday management system where employees submit requests for paid holiday.

I need to create "half-day" for a  given date range for each employee holiday request.

Source Table:
**Request** (where all requests are stored, 1 line for each employee)

```
id (bigint-PK)
begin_date (date)
begin_in_afernoon (bool)
end_date (date)
end_in_morning (bool)
UserID (int)
```

**Sample data:**

```
1 | 08/11/2017 | False | 09/11/2017 | False | 10
```

Destination Table:
**Half_day_absence**

```
Date (date)
Day_Period (string)
Total
UserID
RequestID
```

**Sample data:**

```
08/11/2017 01:00:00 | AM | 0.5 | 10 | 1
08/11/2017 13:00:00 | PM | 0.5 | 10 | 1
09/11/2017 01:00:00 | AM | 0.5 | 10 | 1
09/11/2017 13:00:00 | PM | 0.5 | 10 | 1
```

I'm stuck on how to create the loop for each employee request to insert new lines in the half_day_absence table

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your reply. You code gave me an idea of how I could do the looping. I found another solution however that did not need looping: generate_series() function. Here is a snippet of my sql code if it could be helpful to someone:

```
select 
row_number () over (order by id), --id of new row in destination table
gs as date,
extract(dow from gs) as day_of_week, --Sunday=0/Saturday=6/Monday to Friday=1 à 5
CASE
    WHEN extract(hour from gs) < 13 THEN 'AM'::varchar
    WHEN extract(hour from gs) >=13 THEN 'PM'::varchar
END As day_period
from
(
    select 
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN begin_in_afternoon=false THEN begin_date::date + interval '1' HOUR --business rule: AM started at 1AM
        WHEN begin_in_afternoon=true THEN begin_date::date + interval '13' HOUR --business rule: PM started at 1PM
    END as begin_date,
    CASE
        WHEN end_in_morning=false THEN end_date::date + interval '13' HOUR --business rule: PM started from 1PM
        WHEN end_in_morning=true THEN end_date::date + interval '1' HOUR --business rule: AM started at 1AM
    END as end_date
    from myTable
) h, 
generate_series(h.begin_date, h.end_date, interval '0.5 day')gs
where extract(dow from gs)not in (0,6); --Sunday and Saturday excluded
```

This SELECT is then sent to an INSERT INTO .. clause to insert the resultset into the destination table

Answer (score 0):

Not personnaly tested .. but should be something around this form :

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    nbd integer;
BEGIN
   for rec in select begin_date, begin_in_afernoon, end_date, end_in_morning, userid, EXTRACT('days' FROM (end_date - begin_date)) AS nbdays 
                from holidays;
   LOOP
       nbd = record.nbdays;

       IF end_in_morning = 't' THEN
          INSERT INTO Half_day_absence (begin_date, 'AM', 0.5, record.userid);
       END IF;

       IF end_in_afternoon = 't' THEN
          INSERT INTO Half_day_absence (end_date, 'PM', 0.5, record.userid);
       END IF;

       IF end_in_morning = 'f' AND end_in_afternoon = 'f' THEN
          WHILE nbd > 0 LOOP       
              INSERT INTO Half_day_absence (begin_date + '' || nbd || ''days', 'AM', 0.5, record.userid);
              INSERT INTO Half_day_absence (begin_date + '' || nbd || ''days', 'PM', 0.5, record.userid);
              nbd := nbd - 1;
          END LOOP;
       END IF;

       RETURN next;
   END LOOP;
END
$$;
```

May you should make better periods tests, but the idea is around this formulation.

Hope this help.

Comment: Hi Hervé, Thanks heaps for your reply, I'll test and let you know.